# Apache Spark SQL context dropDuplicates

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to filter DataFrame content, using Spark's 1.5 method **dropDuplicates()**.
Using it with fully data filled tables (I mean no empty cells) gives correct result, but when my CSV source contains empty cells (I'll provide you with source file) - Spark throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. 
What am I doing wrong? I've read Spark SQL and DataFrames tutorial for version 1.6.2, It does not describe DataFrame operations in detail. I am also reading book "Learning Spark. Lightning-Fast Big Data Analysis.", but It's written for Spark 1.5 and operations I need are not described there. I'll be glad to get explanation either link to manual.
Thank you.

```
    package data;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestDrop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DropData dropData = new DropData("src/main/resources/distinct-test.csv");
        dropData.execute();
    }
}

class DropData{

    private String csvPath;
    private JavaSparkContext sparkContext;
    private SQLContext sqlContext;

    DropData(String csvPath) {
        this.csvPath = csvPath;
    }

    void execute(){
        initContext();
        DataFrame dataFrame = loadDataFrame();
        dataFrame.show();
        dataFrame.dropDuplicates(new String[]{"surname"}).show();
        //this one fails too: dataFrame.drop("surname")
    }

    private void initContext() {
        sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("Drop test"));
        sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);
    }

    private DataFrame loadDataFrame() {
        JavaRDD<String> strings = sparkContext.textFile(csvPath);

        JavaRDD<Row> rows = strings.map(string -> {
            String[] cols = string.split(",");
            return RowFactory.create(cols);
        });

        StructType st = DataTypes.createStructType(Arrays.asList(DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("surname", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("sex", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("socialId", DataTypes.StringType, true)));

        return sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, st);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what else do you expect? You declare some number of fields, if it doesn't match you get exception. This is expected behavior. Just filter out malformed data.

Comment: What do you mean It doesn't? I have "surname" column. I expect Spark to filter rows which are duplicates, according to this column, as written in JavaDoc.
Btw, here's my [csv file](http://pastebin.com/NgE6NU8A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending List instead of Object[] results as creation rows, containing 1 column with a list inside. That's what I was doing wrong.